# DFA and regular languages

Tags: theory, dfa

I've been thinking about the following and I think the answer's in the affirmative.

Is it true that every subset of a DFA-acceptable language that is regular is also DFA-acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Counterexample: Alphabet is <strike>numbers</strike> digits.  DFA accepts all natural numbers.  Subset: DFA accepts all prime numbers.

**Edit:** Alphabet is digits.  Sorry, wrong terminology there.

Natural numbers *can* be expressed as a regular language (and therefore a DFA can be constructed for them):

`0|([1-9][0-9]*)`

Comment: Actually, neither of the languages you mention are regular. Both are infinite; the language of prime numbers is not regular, as there is no DFA that could accept it.

Comment: @Marcin You're forgetting that regular expressions actually can express infinite strings, such as `[0-9]*`.

Comment: No. That expresses that there is no upper bound on the length of word that can be accepted; however, to be accepted, some accepting state must be reached after which there are no more elements in the word. Further, this is not the same thing as having an infinite alphabet.

Comment: @Marcin you're right, I can't have an alphabet of all numbers.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Rather than considering primes, just noting that a DFA with an instant truth state accepts all strings is enough. Then, everything is a subset and would be DFA-acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

All finite automata -- deterministic as well as nondeterministic -- can be represented as a regular language and vice versa. If the subset of a language is regular, then *yes* it can be represented as a DFA.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. The question is whether all subsets of a regular language must also be regular, which is false and not addressed here.

Comment: The key point here is: A subset of a regular language is not guaranteed to be regular.